# Installing mysql-devel on RHEL7

Tags: mysql, rhel, rhel7

I have been given a RHEL7 system that has MySQL already installed and
running, and I need to install mysql-devel on it. When I run:

`yum install mysql-devel`

I get:

```
Transaction check error:
  file /usr/bin/mysql_config-64 from install of
mysql-community-devel-5.7.13-1.el7.x86_64 conflicts with file from
package mysql-community-client-5.7.12-1.el7.x86_64
```

What is the best way to resolve this? I do not want to uninstall the
existing running MySQL server. I am not a sysadmin, I am a developer
and there is no admin available at this company.

Output of `yum --showduplicates list mysql-*`:

```
$ sudo yum --showduplicates list mysql-* 
Loaded plugins: langpacks, product-id, search-disabled-repos, subscription-manager
Installed Packages
mysql-community-client.x86_64                     5.7.12-1.el7           @mysql57-community        
mysql-community-common.x86_64                     5.7.12-1.el7           @mysql57-community        
mysql-community-libs.x86_64                       5.7.12-1.el7           @mysql57-community        
mysql-community-libs-compat.x86_64                5.7.12-1.el7           @mysql57-community        
mysql-community-server.x86_64                     5.7.12-1.el7           @mysql57-community        
Available Packages
MySQL-python.x86_64                               1.2.3-11.el7           rhel-7-server-rpms        
MySQL-zrm.noarch                                  3.0-6.el7              epel                      
mysql-community-client.i686                       5.7.9-1.el7            mysql57-community         
mysql-community-client.x86_64                     5.7.9-1.el7            mysql57-community         
mysql-community-client.i686                       5.7.10-1.el7           mysql57-community         
mysql-community-client.x86_64                     5.7.10-1.el7           mysql57-community         
mysql-community-client.i686                       5.7.11-1.el7           mysql57-community         
mysql-community-client.x86_64                     5.7.11-1.el7           mysql57-community         
mysql-community-client.i686                       5.7.12-1.el7           mysql57-community         
mysql-community-client.x86_64                     5.7.12-1.el7           mysql57-community         
mysql-community-client.i686                       5.7.13-1.el7           mysql57-community         
mysql-community-client.x86_64                     5.7.13-1.el7           mysql57-community         
mysql-community-common.i686                       5.7.9-1.el7            mysql57-community         
mysql-community-common.x86_64                     5.7.9-1.el7            mysql57-community         
mysql-community-common.i686                       5.7.10-1.el7           mysql57-community         
mysql-community-common.x86_64                     5.7.10-1.el7           mysql57-community         
mysql-community-common.i686                       5.7.11-1.el7           mysql57-community         
mysql-community-common.x86_64                     5.7.11-1.el7           mysql57-community         
mysql-community-common.i686                       5.7.12-1.el7           mysql57-community         
mysql-community-common.x86_64                     5.7.12-1.el7           mysql57-community         
mysql-community-common.i686                       5.7.13-1.el7           mysql57-community         
mysql-community-common.x86_64                     5.7.13-1.el7           mysql57-community         
mysql-community-devel.i686                        5.7.9-1.el7            mysql57-community         
mysql-community-devel.x86_64                      5.7.9-1.el7            mysql57-community         
mysql-community-devel.i686                        5.7.10-1.el7           mysql57-community         
mysql-community-devel.x86_64                      5.7.10-1.el7           mysql57-community         
mysql-community-devel.i686                        5.7.11-1.el7           mysql57-community         
mysql-community-devel.x86_64                      5.7.11-1.el7           mysql57-community         
mysql-community-devel.i686                        5.7.12-1.el7           mysql57-community         
mysql-community-devel.x86_64                      5.7.12-1.el7           mysql57-community         
mysql-community-devel.i686                        5.7.13-1.el7           mysql57-community         
mysql-community-devel.x86_64                      5.7.13-1.el7           mysql57-community         
mysql-community-embedded.i686                     5.7.9-1.el7            mysql57-community         
mysql-community-embedded.x86_64                   5.7.9-1.el7            mysql57-community         
mysql-community-embedded.i686                     5.7.10-1.el7           mysql57-community         
mysql-community-embedded.x86_64                   5.7.10-1.el7           mysql57-community         
mysql-community-embedded.i686                     5.7.11-1.el7           mysql57-community         
mysql-community-embedded.x86_64                   5.7.11-1.el7           mysql57-community         
mysql-community-embedded.i686                     5.7.12-1.el7           mysql57-community         
mysql-community-embedded.x86_64                   5.7.12-1.el7           mysql57-community         
mysql-community-embedded.i686                     5.7.13-1.el7           mysql57-community         
mysql-community-embedded.x86_64                   5.7.13-1.el7           mysql57-community         
mysql-community-embedded-compat.i686              5.7.9-1.el7            mysql57-community         
mysql-community-embedded-compat.x86_64            5.7.9-1.el7            mysql57-community         
mysql-community-embedded-compat.i686              5.7.10-1.el7           mysql57-community         
mysql-community-embedded-compat.x86_64            5.7.10-1.el7           mysql57-community         
mysql-community-embedded-compat.i686              5.7.11-1.el7           mysql57-community         
mysql-community-embedded-compat.x86_64            5.7.11-1.el7           mysql57-community         
mysql-community-embedded-compat.i686              5.7.12-1.el7           mysql57-community         
mysql-community-embedded-compat.x86_64            5.7.12-1.el7           mysql57-community         
mysql-community-embedded-compat.i686              5.7.13-1.el7           mysql57-community         
mysql-community-embedded-compat.x86_64            5.7.13-1.el7           mysql57-community         
mysql-community-embedded-devel.i686               5.7.9-1.el7            mysql57-community         
mysql-community-embedded-devel.x86_64             5.7.9-1.el7            mysql57-community         
mysql-community-embedded-devel.i686               5.7.10-1.el7           mysql57-community         
mysql-community-embedded-devel.x86_64             5.7.10-1.el7           mysql57-community         
mysql-community-embedded-devel.i686               5.7.11-1.el7           mysql57-community         
mysql-community-embedded-devel.x86_64             5.7.11-1.el7           mysql57-community         
mysql-community-embedded-devel.i686               5.7.12-1.el7           mysql57-community         
mysql-community-embedded-devel.x86_64             5.7.12-1.el7           mysql57-community         
mysql-community-embedded-devel.i686               5.7.13-1.el7           mysql57-community         
mysql-community-embedded-devel.x86_64             5.7.13-1.el7           mysql57-community         
mysql-community-libs.i686                         5.7.9-1.el7            mysql57-community         
mysql-community-libs.x86_64                       5.7.9-1.el7            mysql57-community         
mysql-community-libs.i686                         5.7.10-1.el7           mysql57-community         
mysql-community-libs.x86_64                       5.7.10-1.el7           mysql57-community         
mysql-community-libs.i686                         5.7.11-1.el7           mysql57-community         
mysql-community-libs.x86_64                       5.7.11-1.el7           mysql57-community         
mysql-community-libs.i686                         5.7.12-1.el7           mysql57-community         
mysql-community-libs.x86_64                       5.7.12-1.el7           mysql57-community         
mysql-community-libs.i686                         5.7.13-1.el7           mysql57-community         
mysql-community-libs.x86_64                       5.7.13-1.el7           mysql57-community         
mysql-community-libs-compat.i686                  5.7.9-1.el7            mysql57-community         
mysql-community-libs-compat.x86_64                5.7.9-1.el7            mysql57-community         
mysql-community-libs-compat.i686                  5.7.10-1.el7           mysql57-community         
mysql-community-libs-compat.x86_64                5.7.10-1.el7           mysql57-community         
mysql-community-libs-compat.i686                  5.7.11-1.el7           mysql57-community         
mysql-community-libs-compat.x86_64                5.7.11-1.el7           mysql57-community         
mysql-community-libs-compat.i686                  5.7.12-1.el7           mysql57-community         
mysql-community-libs-compat.x86_64                5.7.12-1.el7           mysql57-community         
mysql-community-libs-compat.i686                  5.7.13-1.el7           mysql57-community         
mysql-community-libs-compat.x86_64                5.7.13-1.el7           mysql57-community         
mysql-community-release.noarch                    el7-5                  mysql-connectors-community
mysql-community-release.noarch                    el7-5                  mysql-tools-community     
mysql-community-release.noarch                    el7-7                  mysql57-community         
mysql-community-server.x86_64                     5.7.9-1.el7            mysql57-community         
mysql-community-server.x86_64                     5.7.10-1.el7           mysql57-community         
mysql-community-server.x86_64                     5.7.11-1.el7           mysql57-community         
mysql-community-server.x86_64                     5.7.12-1.el7           mysql57-community         
mysql-community-server.x86_64                     5.7.13-1.el7           mysql57-community         
mysql-community-test.x86_64                       5.7.9-1.el7            mysql57-community         
mysql-community-test.x86_64                       5.7.10-1.el7           mysql57-community         
mysql-community-test.x86_64                       5.7.11-1.el7           mysql57-community         
mysql-community-test.x86_64                       5.7.12-1.el7           mysql57-community         
mysql-community-test.x86_64                       5.7.13-1.el7           mysql57-community         
mysql-connector-java.noarch                       1:5.1.25-3.el7         rhel-7-server-rpms        
mysql-connector-odbc.x86_64                       5.2.5-6.el7            rhel-7-server-rpms        
mysql-connector-odbc.x86_64                       5.2.6-1.el7            mysql-connectors-community
mysql-connector-odbc.x86_64                       5.2.7-1.el7            mysql-connectors-community
mysql-connector-odbc.x86_64                       5.3.2-1.el7            mysql-connectors-community
mysql-connector-odbc.x86_64                       5.3.4-1.el7            mysql-connectors-community
mysql-connector-odbc.x86_64                       5.3.6-1.el7            mysql-connectors-community
mysql-connector-odbc-debuginfo.x86_64             5.3.6-1.el7            mysql-connectors-community
mysql-connector-odbc-setup.x86_64                 5.3.6-1.el7            mysql-connectors-community
mysql-connector-python.noarch                     1.1.4-1.el7            mysql-connectors-community
mysql-connector-python.noarch                     1.1.5-1.el7            mysql-connectors-community
mysql-connector-python.noarch                     1.1.6-1.el7            epel                      
mysql-connector-python.noarch                     1.1.6-1.el7            mysql-connectors-community
mysql-connector-python.noarch                     1.1.7-1.el7            mysql-connectors-community
mysql-connector-python.noarch                     1.2.2-1.el7            mysql-connectors-community
mysql-connector-python.noarch                     1.2.3-1.el7            mysql-connectors-community
mysql-connector-python.noarch                     2.0.1-1.el7            mysql-connectors-community
mysql-connector-python.noarch                     2.0.2-1.el7            mysql-connectors-community
mysql-connector-python.noarch                     2.0.3-1.el7            mysql-connectors-community
mysql-connector-python.noarch                     2.0.4-1.el7            mysql-connectors-community
mysql-connector-python.x86_64                     2.1.3-1.el7            mysql-connectors-community
mysql-connector-python-cext.x86_64                2.1.3-1.el7            mysql-connectors-community
mysql-connector-python-debuginfo.x86_64           2.1.3-1.el7            mysql-connectors-community
mysql-mmm.noarch                                  2.2.1-14.el7           epel                      
mysql-mmm-agent.noarch                            2.2.1-14.el7           epel                      
mysql-mmm-monitor.noarch                          2.2.1-14.el7           epel                      
mysql-mmm-tools.noarch                            2.2.1-14.el7           epel                      
mysql-proxy.x86_64                                0.8.5-2.el7            epel                      
mysql-proxy-devel.x86_64                          0.8.5-2.el7            epel                      
mysql-router.x86_64                               2.0.2-1.el7            mysql-tools-community     
mysql-router.x86_64                               2.0.3-1.el7            mysql-tools-community     
mysql-router-debuginfo.x86_64                     2.0.2-1.el7            mysql-tools-community     
mysql-router-debuginfo.x86_64                     2.0.3-1.el7            mysql-tools-community     
mysql-utilities.noarch                            1.3.6-1.el7            epel                      
mysql-utilities.noarch                            1.3.6-1.el7            mysql-tools-community     
mysql-utilities.noarch                            1.4.3-1.el7            mysql-tools-community     
mysql-utilities.noarch                            1.4.4-1.el7            mysql-tools-community     
mysql-utilities.noarch                            1.5.2-1.el7            mysql-tools-community     
mysql-utilities.noarch                            1.5.3-1.el7            mysql-tools-community     
mysql-utilities.noarch                            1.5.4-1.el7            mysql-tools-community     
mysql-utilities.noarch                            1.5.5-1.el7            mysql-tools-community     
mysql-utilities.noarch                            1.5.6-1.el7            mysql-tools-community     
mysql-utilities-extra.noarch                      1.4.3-1.el7            mysql-tools-community     
mysql-utilities-extra.noarch                      1.4.4-1.el7            mysql-tools-community     
mysql-utilities-extra.noarch                      1.5.2-1.el7            mysql-tools-community     
mysql-utilities-extra.noarch                      1.5.3-1.el7            mysql-tools-community     
mysql-utilities-extra.noarch                      1.5.4-1.el7            mysql-tools-community     
mysql-utilities-extra.noarch                      1.5.5-1.el7            mysql-tools-community     
mysql-utilities-extra.noarch                      1.5.6-1.el7            mysql-tools-community     
mysql-workbench-community.x86_64                  6.2.3-1.el7            mysql-tools-community     
mysql-workbench-community.x86_64                  6.2.4-1.el7            mysql-tools-community     
mysql-workbench-community.x86_64                  6.2.5-1.el7            mysql-tools-community     
mysql-workbench-community.x86_64                  6.3.3-1.el7            mysql-tools-community     
mysql-workbench-community.x86_64                  6.3.4-1.el7            mysql-tools-community     
mysql-workbench-community.x86_64                  6.3.5-1.el7            mysql-tools-community     
mysql-workbench-community.x86_64                  6.3.6-1.el7            mysql-tools-community     
mysql-workbench-community.x86_64                  6.3.6-2.el7            mysql-tools-community     
mysql-workbench-community-debuginfo.x86_64        6.3.3-1.el7            mysql-tools-community     
mysql-workbench-community-debuginfo.x86_64        6.3.4-1.el7            mysql-tools-community     
mysql-workbench-community-debuginfo.x86_64        6.3.5-1.el7            mysql-tools-community     
mysql-workbench-community-debuginfo.x86_64        6.3.6-1.el7            mysql-tools-community     
mysql-workbench-community-debuginfo.x86_64        6.3.6-2.el7            mysql-tools-community
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you have one step outdated mysql installed.

Try `yum install mysql-community-devel-5.7.12-1.el7`